# Add things to view after successfull authentication

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have an application that let's the user log in via facebook. Im using Facebook SDK:

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView mTextDetails;

    private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
    private static final String TAG = "Facebook";
    private LoginButton login;
    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.i(TAG, " logged in...");
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile(); //Access the profile who Is the person login in

            if(profile != null) {
                //Start to add things to the View here for the logged in user, but how?
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, " Error");
        }

    };

    public LoginFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        //Ask the use for permission to access friends
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");

        //Because we work with fragments
        loginButton.setFragment(this);

        loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, mCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

After the user has logged In, I want to display the view contents that belongs to the users who Is logged In.

But where In the code can I start show the view contents for the logged in user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have almost done, what you need to do is writing another request to get user's info after user logged in successful in onSuccess callback, ex getting user name and email

private FacebookCallback mCallback = new FacebookCallback() {

```
    @Override 
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
          // get user name and email 
           this.getUserInfo();
        } 
    } 
   ...
}


private void getUserInfo()
{
    final GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback callback = new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse)
        {
            if (jsonObject == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            String name = jsonObject.optString("name");
            String email = jsonObject.optString("email");

            // Do something with these data here
        }
    };

    GraphRequest graphRequest = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), callback);
    Bundle params = graphRequest.getParameters();
    params.putString("fields", "name,email");
    graphRequest.setParameters(params);
    graphRequest.executeAsync();

}
```

Remember to add this code, base on what you want to get

// Default permission is public_profile

loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");

You can learn how to use Graph API here 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

Comment: Thank you. But how do I add a new view with a new design to the users who Is successfully logged In?

Comment: @Bryan Should be another question cause i don't know what your root view & new view are which you're using. 

But based on what you asked `add a new view`, I think if your root view is a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout and your new view comes from another xml file, first you can inflate your new view from layout file, then call rootView.addView(newView) or simply setting visibility (visible or gone) of your new view if it's in same xml file.

And another way you can use fragment as your new view, put data from activity to fragment then show it up. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Soon after checking if(profile != null) on line ~19.

Because did you already have the accessToken, user data validated and prevented from being null.

Answer (score 0):

Reference the [link](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-facebook-login-implementation-with-fragment/), you can implement it **onCompleted()**, and don't forget to save the information of user.

```
// When session is changed, this method is called from callback method
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
    Exception exception)
{
    final TextView name = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.name);
    final TextView gender = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.gender);
    final TextView location    = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.location);

    if (state.isOpened()) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
    // make request to the /me API to get Graph user
    Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

        // callback after Graph API response with user
        // object
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
            if (user != null) {
                // Set view visibility to true
                otherView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                // Set User name 
                name.setText("Hello " + user.getName());
                // Set Gender
                gender.setText("Your Gender: "
                        + user.getProperty("gender").toString());
                location.setText("Your Current Location: "
                        + user.getLocation().getProperty("name")
                                .toString());
            }
        }
    }).executeAsync();
} else if (state.isClosed()) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    otherView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

}